# Get permalink and title by post name?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, template-tags

In the theme there is a custom post type called `faq`

I just want to get certain post by its name (NOT by id cause no id exist).

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=faq') ?>
```

how to get `the_tile()` and `the_permalink()` by its name?

Answer (score 4):

```
$posts = get_posts(array('name' => 'your-posts-name', 'post_type' => 'faq'));
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    break; //use this to limit to a single result
}
```

Comment: If you use `name` you will get at most one result, so the `break` is not needed.

Comment: @Jan Fabry true, if your db is consistent. ;-)

Comment: `foreach` loops are for iterating.  Since you are not iterating and instead just using the first item in the array, it makes more sense to do `$post = $posts[0]`.